# how to configure Ngnix as reverse proxy for Phabricator ( Unhandled Exception ("AphrontMalformedRequestException"))

Tags: nginx, proxy, phabricator

I am using phabricator by Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/hachque/phabricator/).
Because my phabricator server is in the LAN of a company, I cannot access it from the outside. I'm trying to use Ngnix as reverse proxy. I can access the login page, but when I try to login, following message was displayed:

> Unhandled Exception ("AphrontMalformedRequestException")   You are
>   trying to save some data to Phabricator, but the request your browser
>   made included an incorrect token. Reload the page and try again. You
>   may need to clear your cookies. This was a Web request. This request
>   had an invalid CSRF token.

Here is part of my Nginx reverse proxy configuration:

```
# phabricator proxy.
#
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  0.0.0.0;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://193.177.1.238/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have same problem, did you solve this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using the same image as you, but what i've installed PHP 7.1 with Nginx and the Phabricator sources on the Docker image, then the Nginx from docker listen to the 9000 port (in my case).

Then i run this image using the `8081:9000` port mapping, and the following VirtualHost config on the Nginx from the **host** machine:

```
upstream api_upstream {
    server 0.0.0.0:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name phabricator.local.com;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://api_upstream;
    }
}
```

the phabricator.local.com host only works if you add this entry to the /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   phabricator.local.com
```

Comment: how about on port 443? when i change into `proxy_pass https://api_upstream;`, it doesn't work